# Problem installing pynput module for python 2

Tags: python-2.x

I am having issues installing one python 2 module (pynput).

In fact I typed the command:

```
sudo pip install pynput
```

It works when I try the following snippet:

```
import pynput
```

but when I type:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
```

The console returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pynput.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pynput
  File "/home/IoTree/server/pynput.py", line 2, in <module>
    from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
ImportError: No module named keyboard
```

Could you please indicate me what's wrong and how to install this module proprely ?

Thank you.

EDIT: I tried with a different .py name (pt.py) and it still doesn't execute without error ..

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure there are no files and/or directories named pynput, pynput.py and pynput.pyc in the directory with the pt.py script?

Comment: There's a pynput.pyc  in the same directory but I wasn't worried about this file as I don't know what is it ... Should I delete it and then retry ?

Comment: Yes, delete it. It's a bytecode (+/- compiled) python file and it's a leftover from before you renamed the pynput.py script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that there are no files and/or directories with the same name of your script are still present in the directory with your script.]

This includes:

- pynput
- pynput.py (python script)
- pynput.pyc (compiled bytecode python script )